# loop over multiple tuples as inputs for another functions

Tags: python-3.x, loops, tuples

I am trying to create a for loop that takes into account multiple tuples that are out_put of a specific function.

how can I introduce them in for loop? for example

tupleA0 = function_plot(a, b,c)

tupleB0 = function_print(c, d,e)

tupleA1 = function_plot(tupleA0[0] , tupleA0[1], tupleB0[2])

tupleB1 = function_print(tupleB0[0] , tupleB0[1], tupleB0[2])

tupleA2 = function_plot(tupleA1[0] , tupleA1[1], tupleB1[2])

tupleB2 = function_print(tupleB1[0] , tupleB1[1], tupleB1[2])

.

.

.

.

etc

could you please help me with some ideas?

kind regards

Mohamad

Comment: You could use the unpacking operator `*`: For example `function_print(tupleB0[0] , tupleB0[1], tupleB0[2])` can be written as `function_print(*tupleB0[)`

Comment: When do you stop? This seems to be a non-ending while loop/recursion

Comment: @JohnColeman , yes but the idea is that how can I introduce the output of pervious tuple as input for the next in a recurrsive loop.
like this example:

for ii in range(10):

      tupleA_ii = function_plot(tupleA_(ii-1)[0] , tupleA_(ii-1)[1], tupleB_(ii-1)[2])

Comment: @Onyambu, I stop once the output of tupleB converge

Comment: @Mohamad converge to what exactly? Or do you mean when the input is the same as the output?

Comment: @Onyambu, the loop should converge to a reference output I have.

Comment: But why do you want something converrge to what you already have? It doesn't make sense. Sorry i do not understand your logic.